# SSE - compare and put my value?

Tags: assembly, sse, simd, intrinsics

I am on this [intel intrinsic guide page](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/).

My sse experience is kind of brittle.

---

Ok, I have an array - a long one, really- of ints named 'source'.

#### Example :

I want to change some of its values if it match a certain value.

```
int source[] = {4,5,9,8}
int mask[] = {4,4,4,4}
int replacer[] = {3,3,3,3}
```

So the final source should look like {3,5,9,8}

**I would like to achieve this using SSE < 4.**

The closest instruction I came across is `_mm_cmpeq_epi32`:

```
FOR j := 0 to 3 
i := j*32 dst[i+31:i] := ( a[i+31:i] == b[i+31:i] ) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0 
ENDFOR
```

Now I would like something to replace the original array with my value, or do nothing otherwise:

```
FOR j := 0 to 3 
i := j*32 dst[i+31:i] := ( a[i+31:i] == b[i+31:i] ) ? my_mask_value_here : source_value_untouched
ENDFOR
```

Is there remotely something achieving what I am trying ? Ican't figure out even when combining different instructions..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having gotten your mask using the `PCMPEQ`, if you have sse 4.1 then you can use the `PBLENDVB` instruction which is specifically for this purpose. Otherwise, you can use `PAND`, `PANDN` and `POR` to emulate it. Also, `MASKMOVDQU` can be used.

Here is the source code demonstrating the 3 ways:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

int main()
{
    int source[] = {4,5,9,8};
    int mask[] = {4,4,4,4};
    int replacer[] = {3,3,3,3};

    __m128i bitmask = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(*(__m128i*)source, *(__m128i*)mask);

    // manual version
    __m128i result = _mm_and_si128(*(__m128i*)replacer, bitmask);
    __m128i tmp = _mm_andnot_si128(bitmask, *(__m128i*)source);
    result = _mm_or_si128(result, tmp);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", *(int*)&result, *((int*)&result + 1), *((int*)&result + 2), *((int*)&result + 3));

    // maskmovdqu version
    result = *(__m128i*)source;
    _mm_maskmoveu_si128(*(__m128i*)replacer, bitmask, (char*)&result);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", *(int*)&result, *((int*)&result + 1), *((int*)&result + 2), *((int*)&result + 3));

    // sse 4.1 version
    result = _mm_blendv_epi8(*(__m128i*)source, *(__m128i*)replacer, bitmask);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", *(int*)&result, *((int*)&result + 1), *((int*)&result + 2), *((int*)&result + 3));
}
```

Comment: No, `maskmovq` only works for mmx, but its friend, the `maskmovdqu`  works with sse however it writes into memory only. May be useful, though.

Comment: The very page you linked shows that it only works with mmx. The `_mm_maskmoveu_si128` is the intrinsic for the `maskmovdqu` but as you can see that takes a memory operand.

Comment: No. void _m_maskmovq (__m64 a, __m64 mask, char* mem_addr)
#include "xmmintrin.h"
Instruction: maskmovq mm, mm
CPUID Flags: SSE

Comment: `__m64` is mmx, not sse even if the instruction is part of the sse set.

Comment: aaah ok! My bad then Jester